# What is cp -f option in makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I am looking at some windows GNU make files.

```
$(CP) -f $(SVM_EULA) $(DEST)
$(CP) $(SVM_OSL) $(DEST)
```

What is the meaning of the -f flag in copy?

Comment: man command ? from where , it is saying "'man' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Where did you get the `makefile`?  Was it originally for Linux?

Comment: This is an option to the POSIX `cp` command.  It means "force" so it will copy the file even if the target file exists.  It won't work with Windows `copy` command.  This makefile is probably written for a POSIX system like Linux or MacOS, or possibly a POSIX shell environment installed on Windows like cygwin.